# Quiero ordenar usuarios por edad usando su Carnet de Identidad

Tags: java

Hola tengo un problema en mi proyecto de 1 er año de ing.informatica .. tengo un arreglo string con numeros de carnet de identidad(identificacion o dni en otros paises)  quiero saber como puedo ordenar este arreglo por edad...

El carnet de identidad viene siendo asi: (siempre 11 digitos)
Por ejemplo yo que naci el 5 de julio de 2000 seria 000705×××××
Osea los 2 primeros digitos representa el año de nacimiento. Por tanto alguien nacido en el 90 seria 90×××××××××  y uno en el 2011 empezaria asi 11×××××××××. Por tanto si lo hiciera ordenando los dos primeros numeros que representan el año, el que haya nacido en 2011 seria mas viejo que el que nacio en el 90 (11>90). He ahi donde surge mi duda....

Comment: Hola y Bienvenido, podrías adjuntar el codigo que tienes, para facilitar que te podamos ayudar

Comment: Tu duda surge porque estás comparando solo los últimos dígitos del año. Por otro lado, estos carnet de identidad que planteas tienen una limitación que no la proporcionas en tu pregunta. Aparte del enunciado de tu tarea, y la duda que tienes, ¿Has intentado algo? Te sugiero que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), luego edita tu pregunta e intenta postear algo de lo que ya has intentado. Saludos

Comment: Los dos primeros digitos son los que dan el año de nacimiento. Los otros 9 pueden ignorarse. Lo que necesito es calcular la edad respecto a 2019  usando el numero de carnet de identidad..

Comment: Pero esto de incluir la fecha en el identificador, es idea tuya? Viene establecido en un ejercicio? Porque no es normal. Alguien nacido el 18 puede tener 1 o 101 años, y son possibles los dos casos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar un número prefijo. Ejemplo para agregar 20 antes de algún número:

```
String tuNum = "00";

int dosmil = 20;
String agregarNum = String.format("%02d", dosmil);

String nuevoNum = agregarNum+tuNum;  // 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues es un poco raro el método pero bueno, puedes tirar de pillería y decir, bueno, estamos en 2019, por lo que no va a haber nadie con un dni mayor a eso, y por otro lado tampoco va a haber gente del 1940 por lo que sabiendo esto puedes hacer que todo lo que sea desde 0 hasta 19 sea menor que una persona que tenga los dos primero dígitos superiores a 19 o 20 por asegurarte un año más.

Suerte con ello!!

Answer (score 0):

Primero, prepara el año actual con 2 cifras (por ejemplo usando el operador modulo, año2cifras=año4cifras%100), y en caso de ser menor al de nacimiento, le sumas 100.
Luego le restas el año de nacimiento, y ya lo tienes.
Eso sí, no va a funcionar para mayores de 99 años.

Ejemplo en Javascript

```js
var añoAct = new Date().getFullYear()%100; // Año actual en 2 cifras.
var añoNac = 77; // Por ejemplo
var edad=añoAct<añoNac?100+añoAct-añoNac:añoAct-añoNac;
console.log (edad);
```